# Test if confidence interval by observation is correct

Tags: confidence-interval, coverage-probability

I have calculated a "confidence interval" of the days between purchase for 600K users. The exact method I used isn't relevant but a simple version would be for each user calculate the distribution between orders and then select the percentile 95 (without assuming any distribution for each user). So this way I end up with a "CI" for each users.

I look at [coverage probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coverage_probability) but seems a bit complicated to perform by users and without a distribution assumption. And at the end I will have if the "CI" by users is correct but not if the general estimation is correct.

I don't know if there exist something that will allow me to test if the estimation is correct or not but is what I'm asking

## EDIT

So a bit of an example of how i calculate the percentile 95. Suppose I just have 1 user with 6 purchases that where done 10, 15, 20, 7 and 17 days between each other. This is between the first order and the second it took 10 days, and between the second and third 15 days and so on. For this user I calculate the percentile 95 of the empirical distribution of the days between orders. This is done in `SQL` but in `R` can be done with a simple `quantile(c(10,15,20,7,17),0.95)`.

I do this for the 600k users which all have different amount of orders, so for some the percentile is actually decent based on the number of orders they have; for others its probably trash. But if in "general" I have more "good" estimations that "bad" ones maybe the overall model is correct. And that's exactly what I want to test.

Comment: Run your method 1000 times on 1000 different samples from your population. If you have about 950 confidence intervals containing the true parameter, then your method has about the right coverage (for a 95% confidence interval).

Comment: @Dave I thought it was correct until i tried to code it. The problem is that I don't calculate 1 "CI" I calculate 600K, one for each user. So what you propose I would have to also sample the number of days between orders for each user to calculate its "CI" but the problem I'm having is the amount of orders to sample for each user (and each user have different number of orders).

Comment: What are you examining with your 600,000 confidence intervals? I’m having trouble imagining why you’re (seemingly) doing one confidence interval per observation. Please edit your question to give more details about what you’re trying to do.

Comment: @Dave i edited with a simple example of how i could "estimate" a CI for each user.

Comment: Agree with @Dave that more details would be helpful. Maybe posting your code could help be specific. It's not clear to me how you have CI with no distributional assumption in the first place, for example. The CI are based on an underlying probability density/ cumulative distribution function of some sort, aren't they? How do you determine what the 0.025 and 0.975 quantiles are right now? That procedure is the thing you are testing when you assess CI coverage.

Comment: @Michael I added and example of how the CI is calculated. I hope is more clear now

Comment: You have at least two questions then. One is, for those customers for whom you have many records, if you compute your quantiles based on very few records (and especially those that are early in the history), are the CI from that correctly containing the mean over their entire history? Second question is whether the customers you have many records from are representative of typical customers/those from whom you have few records. You can probably get CI on the quantiles themselves, e.g. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6294150/